# If $p:E\to B$ is a covering map, then for each $b\in B$ the subspace $p^{-1}(b)$ of $E$ has the discrete topology

Tags: algebraic-topology, proof-explanation, intuition

In Munkres' Topology section 53, he says

> If $p:E\to B$ is a covering map, then for each $b\in B$ the subspace
>   $p^{-1}(b)$ of $E$ has the discrete topology. For each slice $V_\alpha $ is open in $E$ and intersects the set $p^{-1}(b)$ in a single point; therefore, this point is open in $p^{-1}(b)$.

I don't understand what this means. Could anyone explain it with some example? Especially, I want to understand why for each $b\in B$ the subspace $p^{-1}(b)$ of $E$ has the discrete topology. And how each slice $V_\alpha $ intersects the set $p^{-1}(b)$ in a single point.

He also gives an exercise which I think is related to the remark.

> Let $p: E\to B$ be a covering map; let $B$ be connected. Show that if $p^{-1}(b_0)$ has $k$ elements for some $b_0 \in B$, then $p^{-1}(b)$ has $k$ elements for every $b \in B$.

Comment: Each singleton is open in $p^{-1}(b)$ so any other subset of $p^{-1}(b)$ (which is a union of singletons) must be open.

Comment: @Sou This is precisely what the OP is asking for, why each singleton in $p^{-1}(b)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- By construction, $p_{\vert V_\alpha}$ is a homeomorphism onto an open neighborhood of $b$ in $B$, so that the point $b$ has exactly one antecedent by $p$ in $V_{\alpha}$.
- By definition of the induced topology, $p^{-1}(b)\cap V_{\alpha}$ is an open set of $p^{-1}(b)$, since $V_\alpha$ is open in $E$.

Whence the answer to your first question.

For the second one, notice that $B$ is the disjoint union of the sets $B_k$ formed of $b\in B$ such that $p^{-1}(b)$ has cardinality $k$, for $k\in\mathbb{N}\cup\{+\infty\}$ and that each $B_k$ is open. Indeed, if $b\in B_k$, since $p$ is a covering map.

Comment: What do you mean by "$b$ has exactly one antecedent by $p$ in $V_\alpha$"?

Comment: I mean that there exists a unique $e\in V_{\alpha}$ such that $p(e)=b$.

Comment: I think I understand it now. $p^{-1}(b) = \cup_{\alpha \in \mathcal A} (p_{\vert V_\alpha})^{-1}(b) = \{e\in E: p(e) = b\} = \cup_{\alpha \in \mathcal A} \{e\in V_\alpha :  p_{\vert V_\alpha}(e) =b\}$, and each $\{e\in V_\alpha :  p_{\vert V_\alpha}(e) =b\}$ has only one element $p^{-1}(b)\cap V_{\alpha}$ since $p_{\vert V_\alpha}$ is a homeomorphism. $p^{-1}(b)$ is a subspace of $E$ and the single point is open by subspace topology.

Comment: Sorry, I don't see how does local homeomorphism induce $B_k$ is open. Could you explain?

Comment: Good catch, it was false, it is really due to the fact that for $b\in B$, there exists $U$ an open neighbourhood of $b$ such that $p^{-1}(U)$ is the disjoint union of open sets on which $p$ will be a homeomorphism. I have not the time to write it down now, but I believe you can fix it.